# something weird action on iOS5 w/ Custom UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm kind of newbie for iOS programming. While making custom UITabbarController, I got stuck with weird action difference between iOS4 and iOS5. If anyone have an idea for solve this problem, please let me know where i got missed.

## What I wanted is this.

- UITableView / UITabBarController
- Single tap for switching tab bar should work even while scrolling.
- Double tap (and further more) should recognizable.

**UITabBarController + UITapGestureRecognizer + UITableView work together with double tap event.**

## What make me crazy is this.

The very plain **single tap** event for switching tap item, **isn't called** at the time tapped **while UITableView is scrolling.** Instead, the tap changed after scrolling finished.

## Here is how I did.

I want UITabBar to recognize double tab. When it double tapped, scroll UITableView to the top. So I made a project with Tab bar supplement.

- DoubleTapBarController ( Custom UITabBarController )

  - Tab Bar (UITabBar)
  - First VC (Custom UIViewController)

    - default UITabBarItem
  - Second VC (Custom and default blank UIViewController)

    - default UITabBarItem

### In First View / VC

- Plain Table view added with *table Outlet-ed.
- Custom Method 'doubleTapped' for process double tapped event when DoubleTabBarController send message.

### In DoubleTabBarController

- inherit UITabBarController with protocol
- set gestures (single tap, double tap) with UITapGestureRecognizer at viewDidLoad event
- tap1, tap2, tap3, tap4 for tap actions.

### What I tried (and failed).

- Comment requireGestureRecognizerToFail between single/double tap. Didn't work.
- Comment whole double tap recognizer. It works while scrolling. But there is no double tap event.
- Double tap other tab while scrolling. It makes single tap event send while scrolling. But it can't be the solution, too.
- (As I doubt if setting gesture make focus problem - double tap worked at time!) Comment double tap and replace it with triple tap. Triple tap event sent at correct time. But default single tap event didn't work at correct time - like double tap gesture added.

## My Code.

*DoubleTabBarController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DoubleTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarDelegate>
- (id)init;
@end
```

*DoubleTabBarController.m* **(part)**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap1)] autorelease];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap2)] autorelease];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    doubleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
    [[self tabBar] addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [[self tabBar] addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
}
```

### Current state

I lost my direction for solve this problem. Please help me :)

ps. I faced the same problem on iOS 4.3, but it was solved removing UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol. And it occurred again at iOS 5.0 :(